# How to generate pdf file via react-pdf for Ant Design Charts?

Tags: antd, ant-design-pro, react-pdf

We need generate pdf files for online report we build with react and ant design. I am using react-pdf to generate pdf now and wonder how to generate pdf for graph/charts built with "Ant Design Charts"?